# Closing an Overlay Div on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two buttons that open and close an overlay div.

*.trigger-overlay* which is used to show a menu and .overlay-close which is used with multiple overlays to close them.

.wrap wraps all content and which slides right when an overlay is opened by adding the class *.wrap-open*

This works *.trigger-overlay* is clicked but not when *.overlay-close* is clicked. [See example](https://www.uk-cpi.com/temp-js/annual-review/). (click link 1 or link 2 in second slide).

**What do I need to do to the below JS code to remove *.wrap-open* when *.overlay-close* is clicked?**

**JS Fiddle:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/cgx8zu2h/

**Working Example:**
https://www.uk-cpi.com/temp-js/annual-review/

**The JavaScript**

```
(function() {
  var triggerBttn = document.getElementsByClassName('trigger-overlay');
  var closeBttn = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-close');
  var wrap = document.querySelector('div.wrap');
  transEndEventNames = {
      'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
      'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
      'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
      'transition': 'transitionend'
    },
    transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('transition')],
    support = {
      transitions: Modernizr.csstransitions
    };

  function toggleOverlay() {
    var overlay = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-href'));

    // If overlay is open
    if (classie.has(overlay, 'zap')) {

      classie.remove(overlay, 'zap');
      classie.remove(wrap, 'wrap-open');
      classie.add(overlay, 'close');

      var onEndTransitionFn = function(ev) {
        if (support.transitions) {
          if (ev.propertyName !== 'visibility') return;
          this.removeEventListener(transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn);
        }
        classie.remove(overlay, 'close');
      };

      if (support.transitions) {
        overlay.addEventListener(transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn);
      } else {
        onEndTransitionFn();
      }
    }

    // If overlay isn't closed
    else if (!classie.has(overlay, 'close')) {
      classie.add(overlay, 'zap');
      classie.add(wrap, 'wrap-open');
    }
    // If overlay is closed
    else if (classie.has(overlay, 'close')) {
      classie.add(overlay, 'zap');
      classie.add(wrap, 'wrap-open');
    }
  }



  for (var i = 0; i < triggerBttn.length; i++) {
    triggerBttn[i].addEventListener('click', toggleOverlay);
  }

  //counts number of closeBttn and remove zap on click for all
  for (var i = 0; i < closeBttn.length; i++) {
    closeBttn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.parentNode.className = this.parentNode.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)zap(?!\S)/g, '');
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: can u show us your code on Jsfiddle k

Comment: You need to add your HTML markup as well, please.

Comment: JS Fiddle now added: https://jsfiddle.net/cgx8zu2h/

Comment: Working example also added: https://www.uk-cpi.com/temp-js/annual-review/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see - basically I just told **#menu** to be at z-index: 180 .. but I also eliminated your usage of '*classie*', as jquery already has that. And although it's good you know the pure-JS way to get stuff done, if you're already loading jquery why not leverage it?
https://jsfiddle.net/te0s2e86/1/

```
#menu{ z-index: 180; }
```

Comment: Thanks, you have made it more efficient. It's almost there.

1. .wrap-open should be added to .wrap when the links are clicked (but not when the main menu button is clicked)

2. Clicking the main menu button works first time but you will notice when you keep repeat clicking on the menu button, it shows the menu text in it's skewed pre animated state.

Comment: Mmh. Your jsfiddle didn't have that whole wrap-open stuff in it .. I quickly hacked it in - but that causes a whole new set of problems. I've inserted a quick check for whether we're calling this on the menu link or not .. but this now leads to the nav-links showing up once you close the menu on a slide-in view ... some rethinking/regrouping/recoding is needed here! :-/ https://jsfiddle.net/te0s2e86/3/

Comment: This works well now. Having the menu show over the top of the other overlay is fine as it keeps the user in control. My last issue is getting the menu nav items to close all overlays however. Any ideas?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/te0s2e86/4/ - this honours whatever(!) the user clicks in the nav-links. In essence: if(!is_menu) $('.wrap-open,.close,.zap').removeClass('wrap-open close zap');

Comment: With that change the wrap-open needs to be removed from wrap otherwise the user will see nothing but a blank page when clicking on a menu item.